# Content loads very slow in "Tree View" on page load

Tags: javascript, css, laravel

I have a tree view of different products on my website which looks like this:
[Tree View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBiV8.png)

The problem is when I click on one of the menus e.g. "Склад" or "Тест2" the whole page reloads and the menus appear like that for a couple of seconds (while the DOM is loading): [Expanded tree view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEQy1.png)

I don't want my menu to be expanded while I'm waiting to load the contents. Instead, I want to look like this: [Shrunk tree view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9gld.png)

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used laravel, but it sounds like you want your tree to be lazily loaded. What that means is that the page only loads the top level of the tree, then you do an XHR request to load child nodes each time the user expands a branch.

Answer (score 0):

Need more clarity I suppose.

1. You don't want the page to be reloaded? In that case, you need to use AJAX to fetch child data as stated by [Ultimate Gobblement](https://stackoverflow.com/users/421652/ultimate-gobblement).
2. You want the styles to be applied from the start? After going through the screenshots that you've shared, the styles are also not applied in the start in "Expanded Tree View" snapshot. You can achieve this by hiding the menu for sometime, let the styles be loaded and then you can display the whole thing.